# Alterar um Select mysql para um Select PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Eu tenho um Select de fontes cadastradas em uma tabela, e uso atualmente esse código para lista-las para que o usuário possa escolher a fonte desejada.

```
    <select name="tipo_font_end">
    <?php
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fontes");
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $fontes = $res['font'];?>"><?php echo $fontes = $res['font'];?></option>
    <php? } ?>
    </select>
```

Eu gostaria saber como altero para funcionar com essa conexão PDO abaixo.

```
    <?php
    $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site", "root", "");

    $count = 'SELECT * FROM conteudo, cabecalho, rodape, fontes';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($count);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
    ?>
```

Estou inserindo imagem da Tabela Fontes:
[image: Tabela das Fontes]

e estou anexando código da conexao.php para ser verificado se fiz corretamente.

```
    <?php
    $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pbfjacar_site", "root", "");

    $count = 'SELECT * FROM conteudo, cabecalho, rodape, fontes';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($count);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;

    // Código para Select de fontes da rodapa.php

    $count = 'SELECT * FROM fontes';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($count);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;

    foreach($result as $res){
      echo $result['font'];
    }
    ?>
```

Desde já meus agradecimentos pela atenção de todos os amigos.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site", "root", "");

$count = "SELECT * FROM font";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($count);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach($result as $res){
      echo $res['font'];
 }
?>
```

Dentro do `foreach` adeque para que imprima adequadamente à sua necessidade.

Comment: Ricardo coloquei esse código PDO dentro do arquivo conexão.php, e funcionou em parte, pois ele esta buscando somente o primeiro id da tabela, onde possui **mais 9 nomes de fontes cadastradas**.
Como faço para buscar todos?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM fontes` irá pegar tudo de fontes, faça o teste, acesso o console do seu `BD` e insira: `SELECT * FROM fontes` e veja o resultado.

Comment: Ricardo eu verifiquei e consta 10 cadastros na tabela fontes conforme imagem que irei inserir editando a minha pergunta.
E estou anexando o endereço para que vc. possa analisar o que esta acontecendo.
(http://www.pbfjacarepagua.com.br/teste/end.php)

Comment: Editei uma linha no meu código, execute e diga o que vê.

Comment: Pelo que notei, vc. retirou "return $result;".
Eu fiz a alteração e o upload do aquivo para o servidor, e verifiquei no endereço (http://www.pbfjacarepagua.com.br/teste/end.php). Mas continua trazendo somente o primeiro ID com o nome de "Selecione a Fonte...".

Comment: Estranho era pra ta retornado tudo, e este foreach, veja se está executando, coloque um echo 'q<br/>';

Comment: Estranho tambem é que em um select seu é usado `From fontes` mas na tabela ta `font`.

Comment: Olá, coloque o retorno no loop. Quando declaras `$result = x`, atribuis à varivel `$result` apenas o primeiro conujunto de valores retornado pela consulta.

Comment: Não adianta loop pois só há um item. O erro é o uso de `fetch` quando deveria ser `fetchAll`.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, correto vi agora o autor esta usando um mesmo código que tinha o objetivo de recuperar a quantidade de resultados de uma query.

Comment: @MuriloCabral, verifique agora troquei o `fetch` por `fetchAll`.